# Decidability of Unary Languages / One-to-One Mapping

Tags: turing-machines, undecidability, uncountability, mapreduce

I'm trying to prove that there exists an undecidable subset of {1}* by showing a one-to-one correspondence between it and {0, 1}* (which would imply a one-to-one correspondence between their power sets), but I'm struggling with how to do the one-to-one mapping. Isn't it just surjective? That is, there's one unary representation of potentially many binary strings (e.g., 1 = 01 = 0000000000001).

What am I misunderstanding here? Or am I just taking the wrong overall strategy?

(This isn't homework; I'm reviewing for a midterm, and it's a little concerning I'm getting tripped up here)

Comment: Try lexicographic order.

Comment: Could you explain a little more what you mean by that — putting what in lexicographic order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of mapping the string $x\in\{0,1\}^*$ to $1^{\mathrm{bin}(x)}$ (where $\mathrm{bin}(x)$ is the number denoted by interpreting $x$ as a string in binary, map it to $1^{\mathrm{bin}(1x)}$. Now every string in $\{0,1\}^*$ maps to a unique number of $1$s.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest approach is probably to use *unary notation*. The string $1^k$ can be thought of the natural number $k$; $\varepsilon$ is then $0$.

We then have that every unary language corresponds to a unique subset of $\mathbb{N}$ – and vice versa, for every subset of $\mathbb{N}$ we can find a unique language over the alphabet $\{ 1 \}$.

There are uncountably many subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, so there are uncountably many languages over the alphabet $\{ 1 \}$.

Comment: The question already talks about unary notation, which the asker already tried to use. They had a problem, which is exactly what they're asking about, which your answer doesn't address.

Comment: We do not need to involve $\{ 0,1 \}^*$. Unary notation uses a *singleton* alphabet. The mapping $1^k \mapsto k$ is a bijection between $\mathcal{P}(\{ 1 \}^*)$ and $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$.

Comment: Oh, you're saying "Don't prove it via $\{0,1\}^*; prove it this other way, instead." Fair enough.